# Binary heap performance optimization

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, heap

I have implemented a binary heap as a exercise in data structures. I realize that I'm missing some useful functions (increase/decrease key for example) but I don't consider them interesting for the exercise.

I'm interested in learning if there is anything that I could do to improve performance of the `pop` operation which by my benchmarks is the slowest operation. I have already taken it down from the initial 6.5s to 2.5s on my machine.

Compiling and running the below on my machine yields:

> `g++ -O3 --std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic test_heap.cc`
>
> `/a.exe`
>
> `Push time: 177ms Pop time: 2504ms Sum: -2014260032`

I have used `gprof` to profile but the compiler inlines everything into the main function so `gprof` unfortunately doesn't give anything useful in this case. And I don't feel like the results are useful if disabling optimizations to measure performance...

*Note that I'm printing the sum only to avoid the compiler from removing the benchmark code because it isn't used.*

Here is the implementation `heap.hpp`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional> // std::less
#include <utility> // std::swap
#include <stdexcept>

namespace elads{

  // A binary min-heap implemented using the given comparator.
  template<typename T, typename Comparator = std::less<T> >
  class heap{
  public:
    void push(const T& value){
      auto idx = m_data.size();
      m_data.emplace_back(value);
      sift_up(idx);
    }

    void pop(){
      if(m_data.empty()){
        throw std::runtime_error("Stack is empty!");
      }

      if(m_data.size() == 1){
        m_data.clear();
        return;
      }

      swap(0, m_data.size() - 1);
      m_data.erase(m_data.end()-1);
      sift_down(0);
    }

    const T& top() const {
      if(m_data.empty()){
        throw std::runtime_error("Stack is empty!");
      }
      return m_data.front();
    }

    bool empty() const{
      return m_data.empty();
    }

  private:
    std::vector<T> m_data;
    Comparator m_cmp;

    bool less(size_t lhs, size_t rhs) const{
      return m_cmp(m_data[lhs], m_data[rhs]);
    }

    void swap(size_t lhs, size_t rhs){
      using std::swap;
      swap(m_data[lhs], m_data[rhs]);
    }

    void sift_up(size_t child){
      if(root(child))
        return;
      auto parent = parent_of(child);
      if(!less(parent, child)){
        swap(parent, child);
        sift_up(parent);
      }
    }

    void sift_down(size_t parent){
      auto left = left_of(parent);
      auto right = right_of(parent);

      // Note: "right <= parent" means that the index calculation of the right child overflowed.
      // Assume: 0 <= parent < 2^k  (i.e. parent is valid index) for some positive k depending on the index type.
      // The index of right is calculated as: 
      //
      //     right = 2*parent + 2 (0)
      //
      // Then an overflow that the above test would return false for can only occurr if:
      //     
      //     (2*parent + 2 =) (parent + x) % (2^k) > parent  (1)
      //
      // Where x = parent + 2. Inequality (1) can only be true if:
      // 
      //     x = n*2^k + y; where "n >= 1" and "0 < y < 2^k - parent" (2).
      //
      // Now we know that "parent < 2^k" thus "n >= 1" can only occur if "2^k - 2 <= parent < 2^k"
      // so we can test the two cases:
      // 
      // Case: parent = 2^k - 2
      // From the above we know that n=1. Inserting "parent = 2^k - 2"  into (2) yields: 0 < y < 2 
      // and calculating y yields y = 0, thus this case contradicts (1).
      // 
      // Case: parent = 2^k - 1
      // From the above we know that n=1. Inserting "parent = 2^k - 1" into (2) yields: 0 < y < 1
      // and calculating y yields y = 1. This case too contradicts (1). 
      //
      // Thus we have proven that if "right <= parent" is sufficienct and necessary conditions for
      // detecting if an overflow has occurred. For the left index replace "2*parent + 2" with "2*parent + 1"
      // and repeat the same steps. The result will be that the first case cannot occurr.

      auto has_right = right < m_data.size() && right > parent; // right > parent == !(right <= parent) - overflow
      auto has_left = left < m_data.size() && left > parent;

      if(has_right && less(right, parent)){
        // By design, left < right so if has_right is true then has_left is also true.
        if(less(left, right)){
          swap(left, parent);
          sift_down(left);
        }
        else{
          swap(right, parent);
          sift_down(right);
        }
      }
      else if(has_left && less(left, parent)){
        swap(left, parent);
        sift_down(left);
      }
      // Else, well we're either on the last level or the heap property holds
    }

    size_t parent_of(size_t index) const{
        return (index - 1)/2;
      }

    size_t left_of(size_t index) const{
        return 2*index + 1;
      }

    size_t right_of(size_t index) const{
        return 2*index + 2;
      }

    bool root(size_t index) const{
        return index == 0;
    } 
  };

}
```

Here is the benchmark/test harness `test_heap.cpp`:

```
#include "heap.hpp"

#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

template<typename TimeT = std::chrono::milliseconds>
struct measure
{
     template<typename F, typename ...Args>
     static typename TimeT::rep execution(
     F func, Args&&... args)
     {
         auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
         func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
         auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<
            TimeT>(
             std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start);
         return duration.count();
     }
};

int main(){
  // Setup test data
  const auto n = 10000000;
  auto rng = std::mt19937(std::clock());
  std::vector<int> dataset(n);
  std::iota(dataset.begin(), dataset.end(), 0);
  std::shuffle(dataset.begin(), dataset.end(), rng);

  // Begin test
  elads::heap<int> heap;

  auto push_time_ms = measure<>::execution([&](){
      for(auto v : dataset){
        heap.push(v);
      }
    });

  int sum = 0;
  auto pop_time_ms = measure<>::execution([&](){
      int expected = 0;
      while(!heap.empty()){
        assert(expected++ == heap.top());
        sum += heap.top();
        heap.pop();
      }
    });

  std::cout<<"Push time: "<<push_time_ms<<"ms Pop time: "<<pop_time_ms<<"ms Sum: "<<sum<<std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: For instruction-level profiling you can use, for example, linux's `perf` utility.

Comment: Another thing you can try is to transform recursion to iteration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Drop the checks**

Right now, your `pop()` and `top()` both check for emptiness and throw. `assert()` would be better - you don't want these functions throwing. It's likely that your user will check for `empty()` first anyway - and if they don't, make sure they understand that they have to. With that, our `top()` becomes trivial:

```
const T& top() const {
    return m_data.front();
}
```

And our `pop()` is a few lines shorter.

**Swapping**

Two unrelated comments to make about swapping. First, in your `pop()`, you swap the first and last elements and then erase the last one. But you don't actually need to do that. We don't care that the last element *is* the first one when we erase it. Just move the last one into the first one:

```
m_data.front() = std::move(m_data.back());
m_data.pop_back();
```

That'll save some unnecessary operations.

The second comment is about your member function `swap()`. It's a little confusing in that it doesn't swap the arguments passed in - it swaps those indices. So prefer to name it `swap_idx()` or something along those lines just for clarity.

**Special cases**

In your `pop()`, you start with the special case that `size() == 1`. But there's nothing special about that case for the purpose of your algorithm. `sift_down()` will just do nothing. So you don't need it. That reduces your `pop()` down to:

```
void pop() {
    m_data.front() = std::move(m_data.back());
    m_data.pop_back();
    sift_down(0);
}
```

**Overflow**

You have this enormous comment block and logic in `sift_down()` describing overflow cases for indices. You are really not going to have a heap large enough to have potential for overflow. I wouldn't worry about it. It just makes your logic more complicated than it needs to be. Drop it.

**Push it. Push it real good**

If you have `push(const T&)`, you may as well add `push(T&& )`, and then while we're at it, also add `emplace(Args&&...)`. You could have them all forward to a common implementation:

```
void push(const T& value) { emplace(value); }
void push(T&& value) { emplace(std::move(value); }

template <class... Args>
void emplace(Args&&... args) {
    auto idx = m_data.size();
    m_data.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    sift_up(idx);
}
```

**Arbitrary Comparators**

If you allow for a templated `Comparator` - you need to allow the user to pass one in via a constructor. As-is, it really only works with default-constructible types. Furthermore, I'd suggest inheriting from the comparator to take advantage of the empty base optimization - `std::less<>` for instance is empty, so can save that space.

Comment: 1. Converting a non-throwing function into a throwing one is great for debugging? Not so much, aborting on finding an error in the debug build which won't be handled gracefully in the release build is much more reasonable, as would happen with `assert`. 2. `swap_idx`? That abbreviation doesn't actally buy anything, and considering there's `std::iter_swap`, `index_swap` seems more appropriate.

Comment: @Deduplicator 1. I meant debugging during creating the class. 2. You're really suggesting `index_swap` over `swap_index`? Ok.

Comment: Removing the special case on size 1 and the checks gives about a 0.5% performance increase in a hot loop for pop/top.  In other words, not distinguishable from normal run-to-run variation. Which is very understandable as the CPU will branch predict the checks correctly just about every time and the latency incurred is about 1/IPC or ~0.1 cycle for a modern CPU. I'll measure the other advice and get back to you.

Comment: Actually `m_data.front() = std::move(m_data.back())` isn't really safe if `m_data.size() == 1` because a move assignment operator usually assumes that the argument isn't aliasing `this` because normally rvalue references only binds to temporaries, or the user has lied to you making you believe you bound to a temporary (which we do when size == 1.

Comment: @EmilyL. It's safe if `T`'s move assignment operator is correctly written.

Comment: @Barry I refer to Scott Meyers on this ["...per 17.6.4.9 of both C++11 and C++14, the policy of the Standard Library is that self-move-assignment generally leads to undefined behavior..."](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2014/06/the-drawbacks-of-implementing-move.html?showComment=1403653665782#c8830876598907551665). You may also wish to look at the linked [defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#1204): "Additionally this clarifies that move assignment operators need not perform the traditional if (this != &rhs) test..."